# Maven Release: How to skip deploy step?

Tags: maven, maven-release-plugin

To release my app I am using **maven-release-plugin**.

One step in this process is deploying the release into the repository. **I would like to avoid this step**, but when I remove distributionManagement from my pom file I am getting the error:

```
Deployment failed: repository element was not specified in the POM inside distributionManagement element
```

How to configure maven-release-plugin to skip deploying?

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: Why would you like to to avoid that? Are you not working with a repository?

Comment: The plugin will do several things for me, eg.: increase version, create a tag in the git repo, etc. All of these are very useful, but I really don't need to deploy jar for every release. May sounds funny but I do release quite often (several times a day) and I dont have that much space on VPS :).   If I need to get the old version in the future, I can check out the tag and build it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is nothing unusual or funny to release several times a day..space issue might be questionable but this is a separate discussion.

You can configure the [maven release plugin](https://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/perform-mojo.html) what kind of goals will be done during the release. This can be achieved by configuring the plugin in a pluginManagement at best. And also you should define all the versions of all plugins you are using (most of the time it is most convenient to create a parent pom for your environment).

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <arguments>${arguments}</arguments>
    <goals>The Goal You would like to execute</goals>
    <autoVersionSubmodules>true</autoVersionSubmodules>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

So you could define to only make `install` instead of deploy like this:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <arguments>${arguments}</arguments>
    <goals>install</goals>
    <autoVersionSubmodules>true</autoVersionSubmodules>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 2):

As [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23222265/6309), you can use:

```
mvn release:perform -Darguments="-Dmaven.deploy.skip=true"
```

(which is also available on other plugins, like [`github-release-plugin`](https://github.com/cy6erGn0m/github-release-plugin#plugin-configuration-options))

As seen in [`glib-briia/cucumber-jvm-scala` `pom.xml`](https://github.com/glib-briia/cucumber-jvm-scala/blob/b0828757a7206ca5c86411bdabb8c7b17410357a/pom.xml#L148-L160), you can also define a profile in your pom.xml in order to activate the `skip` when you want.

Comment: Arguments will only work if you have configured the maven-release-plugin within your hierarchy accordingly. Apart from that if you have to do that several times you likely miss the parameters and makes it more inconvenient than necessary.

Comment: A profile means you have to add the option to the command line which is is not very convenient...